Error on adding C linkers in Vivado using xsc Compiler
I am currently exploring Vivado and SystemVerilog, and I'm working on a simple prototype to better understand SystemVerilog DPI and endpoint concepts in windows.
In my prototype, I have followed a Vivado DPI import example as a reference [https://docs.amd.com/r/2021.2-English/ug900-vivado-logic-simulation/Compiling-C-Code]. The prototype involves starting a Python TCP server externally. Then, when executing the Vivado simulator, SystemVerilog is expected to call a cFunc function from a C program. This cFunc
function contains the logic for creating a TCP client and sending the string "Hello, server" to the server.
However, during simulation, I encountered an error in the C program, which reads as follows:
./xsim.dir\work\xsc\dpi.a(function.win64.obj):function.c:(.text+0x22): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAStartup'

./xsim.dir\work\xsc\dpi.a(function.win64.obj):function.c:(.text+0x55): undefined reference to `__imp_socket'

./xsim.dir\work\xsc\dpi.a(function.win64.obj):function.c:(.text+0x7b): undefined reference to `__imp_WSACleanup'

./xsim.dir\work\xsc\dpi.a(function.win64.obj):function.c:(.text+0xb6): undefined reference to `__imp_htons'

./xsim.dir\work\xsc\dpi.a(function.win64.obj):function.c:(.text+0xde): undefined reference to `inet_pton'

./xsim.dir\work\xsc\dpi.a(function.win64.obj):function.c:(.text+0xff): undefined reference to `__imp_closesocket'

./xsim.dir\work\xsc\dpi.a(function.win64.obj):function.c:(.text+0x108): undefined reference to `__imp_WSACleanup'

./xsim.dir\work\xsc\dpi.a(function.win64.obj):function.c:(.text+0x132): undefined reference to `__imp_connect'

./xsim.dir\work\xsc\dpi.a(function.win64.obj):function.c:(.text+0x156): undefined reference to `__imp_closesocket'

./xsim.dir\work\xsc\dpi.a(function.win64.obj):function.c:(.text+0x15f): undefined reference to `__imp_WSACleanup'

./xsim.dir\work\xsc\dpi.a(function.win64.obj):function.c:(.text+0x1ab): undefined reference to `__imp_send'

./xsim.dir\work\xsc\dpi.a(function.win64.obj):function.c:(.text+0x1cf): undefined reference to `__imp_closesocket'

./xsim.dir\work\xsc\dpi.a(function.win64.obj):function.c:(.text+0x1d8): undefined reference to `__imp_WSACleanup'

./xsim.dir\work\xsc\dpi.a(function.win64.obj):function.c:(.text+0x205): undefined reference to `__imp_recv'

./xsim.dir\work\xsc\dpi.a(function.win64.obj):function.c:(.text+0x233): undefined reference to `__imp_closesocket'

./xsim.dir\work\xsc\dpi.a(function.win64.obj):function.c:(.text+0x23c): undefined reference to `__imp_WSACleanup'

./xsim.dir\work\xsc\dpi.a(function.win64.obj):function.c:(.text+0x276): undefined reference to `__imp_closesocket'

./xsim.dir\work\xsc\dpi.a(function.win64.obj):function.c:(.text+0x27f): undefined reference to `__imp_WSACleanup'

To provide context, I have included the necessary winsock2.h header in my C program, and I have added the C linker option in the run.bat script as follows
call %install_root%\bin\xsc function.c --gcc_link_options -Lws2_32 "C:\Windows\System32"
I would greatly appreciate any guidance or assistance you can provide in resolving this issue.

I see 64 in the error messages but 32 in your linker command. The issue is probably that you're trying to pass a 32-bit library while linking for 64-bit. I'm specifically referring to -Lws2_32.

Tudor, thank you for your response. Despite adjusting the library's bitness, the issue persists. Below is the batch file for your reference: call set install_root="C:\Xilinx\Vivado\2023.2" call %install_root%\bin\xvlog -sv file.sv call %install_root%\bin\xelab TOP -dpiheader dpi.h  call %install_root%\bin\xsc function.c --compile function.c call %install_root%\bin\xsc function.c --shared function.c -i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.22000.0\um\x64\WS2_32.Lib" call %install_root%\bin\xelab TOP -sv_lib dpi -R

Still seems like it's missing things that should be available in the Winsock library. I don't really know how compilation works on Windows, so I can't really help much here. I did a quick search and found that you might also need to explicitly pass wsock32 as well: https://github.com/ggerganov/llama.cpp/issues/2255. Might be better to ask in the Xilinx forum.
